# Upgrading Node JS and ERR_REQUIRE_ESM: Must use import to load ES Module: 'inheritsloose.js' of Babel Runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, babeljs

The following error is emitted in my Node JS/React JS application after upgrading Node JS to v.12. I'm currently using @babel/core 7.10.1. How should this error be resolved?

[image: Log of error emitted from Babel]

Here is my babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: 'current',
        },
      },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-react',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements',
  ],
  ignore: ['node_modules', 'build'],
};
```

Comment: I have the same problem under Ubuntu 18.04. Everything throws this error: Next.js, PM2…

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `"type": "module"` from `package.json`.

I've spend many hours with no luck and finally found this commend in discussion:

https://github.com/manuelbieh/geolib/issues/208#issuecomment-556994420

**You have `ignore: ['node_modules', 'build']`, maybe, that's the reason?**

Comment: Unfortunately, the package.json belongs to an external NPM library (@babel/runtime). I cannot mod this file.

Comment: Try to do the same in that package just for experimenting.

Comment: React JS written in Typescript

Comment: Can you prepare minimal example with that lib, that reproduces the error? Post somewhere, to make me or someone to take a look.

Comment: You have `ignore: ['node_modules'…`, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Hello @AntonAL, thanks for your comments. I resolved the issue. I had nested package.json files within my application. These package.json files defined dependencies. I believe that parts of the app were being transpiled with different versions of Babel. I flattened my application and removed the nested package.json files. This action solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had nested package.json files within my application. These package.json files defined dependencies. I believe that parts of the app were being transpiled with different versions of Babel. I flattened my application and removed the nested package.json files. This action solved my problem.